# how add the scene in particular region in android gaming using andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

I am new to game development.am using and-engine to develop the game.am create the scene like fall of object randomly from top of the screen use code below.

```
    TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler;
    float mEffectSpawnDelay = 3f;

    spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay, true,
    new ITimerCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            Random rand = new Random();

            int y = (int) (resourcesManager.camera.getHeight() + resourcesManager.ball2.getHeight());
            int minx = (int) (resourcesManager.ball1.getHeight());
            int maxx = (int) (resourcesManager.camera.getWidth() - resourcesManager.ball2.getWidth());
            int rangex = maxx- minx;
            int x = rand.nextInt(rangex) + minx;

            Sprite target = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.ball2.deepCopy(),vbom);
            attachChild(target);

            int minDuration = 4;
            int maxDuration = 8;
            int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
            int actualDuration = rand.nextInt(rangeDuration) + minDuration;

            MoveYModifier mod = new MoveYModifier(actualDuration, target.getY(),-target.getHeight());
            target.registerEntityModifier(mod.deepCopy());

            TargetsToBeAdded.add(target);
        }
    });

    registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler);
```

from this code the object comes from the top of the screen but it comes all over the width.I want to set fall of the object from half of the screen to till end of the screen.Can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int minx = (int) (resourcesManager.camera.getWidth() / 2);
```

Comment: it comes only in center of the screen.not comes till end of the screen.

Comment: I think this should help you - int rangex = maxx;